# how to calibrate a 2D camera with respect to Kinect?

Tags: calibration, kinect, camera-calibration, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I have a 2D thermal imaging camera mounted right on top of my kinect. I am trying to calibrate these two sensors so as to integrate data from them. Is there a way to do this using any of ROS packages or external libraries? Also, if you know of a way of calibrating a regular camera with kinect please feel free to share.

Please feel free to share any references or solutions on this problem.Best,

CV

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9257/how-to-calibrate-a-2d-camera-with-respect-to-kinect?/) by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 284 on 2011-03-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-03**:
Could you clarify what type of calibration you are looking for? For example, are you just trying to find the rotation/translation of the 2D camera relative to one of the Kinect's cameras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For calibrating the intrinsic camera parameters of a thermal camera I had satisfactory (if not perfect) results by warming the checkerboard pattern using a high powered lamp. The black squares will get hotter than the white squares and show up differently on thermals after a short while. I did that with the Matlab toolbox where one has to manually click the correspondences though, not sure how OpenCV calibration copes with sometimes not so perfect images (due to not perfectly homogenous heating, low resolution, noise in the framegrabbed images etc).
We also considered making a calibration pattern out of metal squares, but ditched that idea because the "paper heating" method worked well enough.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1